# Configure jenkins plugin/ credentials values with api

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I want to know if there is jenkins api (a remote access api) to set values in jenkins plugin configuration. For example artifactory plugin asks for artifactory URL only in configuration manager (http://jenkins-url/configure) and a new url cannot be created while creating a job.

Also how can we create new credentials (ssh/ username, password) on jenkins system with jenkins remote API.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example: https://gist.github.com/iocanel/9de5c976cc0bd5011653

```
import jenkins.model.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.*
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.*
import hudson.plugins.sshslaves.*;

domain = Domain.global()
store = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0].getStore()

priveteKey = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey(
CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
"jenkins-slave-key",
"root",
new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey.UsersPrivateKeySource(),
"",
""
)

usernameAndPassword = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl(
  CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
  "jenkins-slave-password", "Jenkis Slave with Password Configuration",
  "root",
  "jenkins"
)

store.addCredentials(domain, priveteKey)
store.addCredentials(domain, usernameAndPassword)
```